# Add/Append text to the end of multiple lines in a specific range in a text file

Tags: python, file, text

I'm trying to append different text to the end of multiple lines in a specific range to a text file using python programming.

Example data in my text file:

```
Cat 1: 27
Cat 2: 33
Cat 3: 15
Cat 4: 
Cat 5: 
Cat 6: 
Cat 7: 89
```

I want to append this set of data to the lines with text "Cat 4" through "Cat 6":

```
44
22
64
```

I want the output of the python program to do this:

```
Cat 1: 27
Cat 2: 33
Cat 3: 15
Cat 4: 44
Cat 5: 22
Cat 6: 64
Cat 7: 89
```

I found this code online, but it only replaces text with new text. It doesn't append text and you have to use separate files to achieve it:

```
# create a dict of find keys and replace values
findlines = open('find.txt').read().split('\n')
replacelines = open('replace.txt').read().split('\n')
find_replace = dict(zip(findlines, replacelines))

with open('data.txt') as data:
    with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as new_data:
        for line in data:
            for key in find_replace:
                if key in line:
                    line = line.replace(key, find_replace[key])
            new_data.write(line)
```

So far, I can't figure out what code I need as I'm new to programming. What python code do I need to achieve this and how can I get it to work with one file instead of three? Also, how do I get the program to read one line at a time instead of loading all the data into memory at once? I want to be able to use this program for lots of text files like this and I don't want it to freeze my computer up because of a large amount of data in a text file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is open the file for reading and writing, read each line, and then extract the Cat `number`, compare it with the ones you are interested in replacing, and append the new text to the line. When you parsed all the lines, you set the pointer to the start of the file, and write it again, for example:

```
import re

numbers = [44, 22, 64]
start = 4
end = 6

pattern = re.compile(r'^Cat (\d+):')

with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    updated_lines = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()

        match = pattern.match(line)
        number = int(match.group(1)[0])

        if start <= number <= end:
            add_number = numbers[number - start]
            line = line + ' ' +  str(add_number)

        updated_lines.append(line + '\n')

    file.seek(0)
    file.writelines(updated_lines)
```

Comment: I tried the example and I got this: line 19
    line = f"{line} {add_number}" 
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ubuntuuser771 it means that `fstrings` are not available for your `python` version. check the edit.

Comment: I have python2 version 2.7.18 and python3 version 3.8.5 installed on Ubuntu 20.04.2. I tried the code with the fstrings and got the following errors: For Python2: line 19
    line = f"{line} {add_number}"
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

For Python3: line 15, in <module>
    number = int(match.group(1)[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: With the new code, I got these errors:
For Python2: line 15, in <module>
    number = int(match.group(1)[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

For Python3: line 15, in <module>
    number = int(match.group(1)[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: The program works with the example I provided above in my question using python3. The previous one with the fstrings doesn't work with python2. When I change the text in my text file from "Cat =" to something like "4-1= ", I get this error with python3: line 15, in <module>
    number = int(match.group(1)[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. I also want to use this program with multiple different text files with different texts like this while appending other words, characters, letter, numbers, etc to each of them individually. Will that be possible? Thanks.

Comment: it's failing because the pattern doesn't match what you wrote if you keep changing it. u need to stick with a pattern in order it to work. if this answers your question, consider upvoting and selecting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Have a nice day.